# A 10th grade physics problem regarding the velocity of a wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

There is a question in one of my textbooks:

> Frequency of vibration in a wire is $500Hz$ and distance covered by the wave in $1s$ is $20cm$. Find the velocity of the wave.

The options are:

> (a) $150ms^{-1}$ (b)$10000 ms^{-1}$ (c)$1000 cms^{-1}$ (d)$100 ms^{-1}$

How does that make sense? Are the options wrong? If the wave covers a distance of $20cm$ in $1s$, isn't the speed $20cms^{-1}=0.2ms^{-1}$?

What does it mean by the question then? The answer key claims that the answer is option (d)$100ms^{-1}$, and they have considered the $20 cm$ to be the wavelength and used the formula $v=f\lambda$, but how is that the wavelength?

Is the question wrong?

Comment: looks like you're right on this one

Comment: Alright lol, the book is at fault then?

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: @nasu sorry for the late reply; unfortunately, I don't know the name of the book, my teacher shared with us pictures of some questions for practise, and that is where I found it

Answer (score 4):

Judging by their answer, there may be a typo, and they meant "20 cm in 1 cycle".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I think that will still be wrong, as they will have to change that it's not the "distance traveled" in one cycle but the "displacement" of the wave in one cycle

Comment: Not really.  The wavelength is indeed equal to the distance travelled in 1 period.  Anyway, for motion (or propagation) in a straight line the displacement is equal in magnitude with distance travelled.